# Issue with Snake Head colliding with snake body Java (Processing)

Tags: java, arrays, processing

I have started a Snake game for a University project and I am currently having an issue where the first segment of the body stored in an array is in the same location as the head. I don't quite know how I would go about offsetting the position of the first segment of the body so it isn't in the same position as the head part.

I noticed this when I was creating collision detection between the body and the head and it wasn't working as the first segment was in the same position as the head.

**MainApp.java**

```
import processing.core.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * Created by Wills on 25/05/2018.
 */
public class MainApp extends PApplet{
    Snake snake;
    Food food;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        PApplet.main("MainApp", args);
    }
    int screenSize = 800;
    int scale = 20;
    public void settings(){
        size(screenSize,screenSize);
        snake = new Snake(width/2, height/2, 0, 1, scale, screenSize );
        food = new Food(screenSize, scale);
    }
    public void setup(){
        frameRate(10);
        rect(food.getX(), food.getY(), scale, scale);
    }
    public void draw() {
        background(0);
        snake.update();
        fill(255);
        rect(snake.getX(), snake.getY(), snake.getScale(), snake.getScale());
        if(snake.getX()  == food.getX() && snake.getY() == food.getY()){
            snake.eat();
        }
        for(Point p: snake.getBody()){
            if(food.getX() == p.getX() && food.getY() == p.getY()){
                food.rePos();
            }
            rect((float)p.getX(), (float)p.getY(), snake.getScale(), snake.getScale());
        }
        fill(255,0,0);
        rect(food.getX(), food.getY(), scale, scale);
    }
    public void mouseClicked(){
        snake.eat();
        snake.eat();
        snake.eat();
        snake.eat();
    }
    public void keyPressed(){
        if(key == 'a'){
            snake.setDirection(-1, 0);
        }
        if(key == 'd'){
            snake.setDirection(1, 0);
        }
        if(key == 'w'){
            snake.setDirection(0, -1);
        }
        if(key == 's'){
            snake.setDirection(0, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Snake.java**

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Wills on 25/05/2018.
 */
public class Snake extends PApplet{
    int x, y, yspeed, xspeed, scale;
    int score;
    int screenSize;
    ArrayList<Point> body;
    public Snake(int x, int y, int xspeed, int yspeed, int scale, int screenSize){
        body = new ArrayList<Point>();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.xspeed = xspeed;
        this.yspeed = yspeed;
        this.scale = scale;
        this.screenSize = screenSize;
    }
    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setDirection(int x, int y){
        this.xspeed = x;
        this.yspeed = y;
    }
    public float getScale(){
        return scale;
    }
    void update(){
        x = constrain(x + xspeed * scale,0, screenSize - scale);
        y =constrain(y + yspeed * scale,0, screenSize - scale);
        body.add(0, new Point(x, y));
        body.remove(score);
    }
    void eat(){
        body.add(new Point(x,y));
        score ++;
        System.out.println(score);

    }
    void kill(){
        score = 0;
        x = screenSize/2;
        y = screenSize/2;
    }
    ArrayList<Point> getBody(){
        return body;
    }

}
```

**Food.java**

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Wills on 25/05/2018.
 */
public class Food extends PApplet{
    float screenSize;
    int scale, x, y;
    Food(int screenSize, int scale){
        this.scale = scale;
        this.screenSize = screenSize;
        generate();
    }
    float getX(){
        return x;
    }
    float getY(){
        return y;
    }
    public void rePos() {
        generate();
    }
    private void generate(){
        x = floor(random(0, scale));
        y = floor(random(0, scale));
        x = (int) map(x, 0, scale, 0, screenSize);
        y = (int) map(y, 0, scale, 0, screenSize);
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Side note: why does everything extend `PApplet`? Besides that, did you debug your code? I can't/won't do that for you, but let me ask some questions: When does a body segment get added? Do you add it after moving the head or before moving the head?

Comment: The snake.eat() is called after the snake.update() but this all happens in the same frame of draw(). So the new segment is added at the location of the head and then is shifted in the array every frame in snake.update()

Comment: Why does `eat()` add another point, especially when `x` and `y` haven't changed? Why does `update()` remove the element at `score`? Do you realize that what you pass to the `remove(int)` method is the index of the element you want to remove and that that index might not exist or point to another element after shifting?

Comment: In general I'd probably do it like this: 1) move the head and add a new body segment at the head's previous position 2) check for a collision and if there is one, check whether it was the last body segment: if it was the last element you're fine since that element would be removed anyways (food can't spawn there - you need to prevent that), if it wasn't the last body segment it's game over. 3) If you didn't collide with the body (last segment doesn't count) check whether you ate some food. If no then remove the last body segment, otherwise keep it.

Comment: `eat()` adds another point because when the fruit is eaten the length of the snakes body increase by 1. The point of the removal of the element at score is it is equal to the last position in the arrayList, the point of this is to stop the snake from growing each update but to only grow on eat. I guess it would make more sense to `dobody.remove(body.size() - 1);`